# Having trouble scaling a webcam stream to the iframe container size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scale

I'm trying to embed a camera feed into a page which will display manual focus and servo controls. However, I cannot get past the scaling of the content within the iframe.

The iframe boundary resizes to the width of the window. However the embedded page (which is an mjpeg page generated by an application) is not being scaled.

Here's the markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ustreamer Webcam</title>
    <style>
      .icontainer {
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 100%; /* set the aspect ratio here as (height / width) * 100% */
        height: 0;
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .icontainer iframe {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='icontainer'>
      <iframe src='http://abc.def.com:5001/webcam/?action=stream' allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you think it is at all possible? The source page is out of my hands, unless there is no option. It just poses other complications.

Comment: The URL you are embedding there returns an image data stream, the browser will create a rudimentary HTML document around that, and an `img` element. A plain image has no reason to "scale" to anything by its own volition - and since the iframe content is from a different origin, you can't easily inject your own styling either. But you should be able to simply use an `img` instead of an `iframe` to begin with, to embed this into your page ... and then you can format that image directly.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I had no idea the img tag could work with such a video feed. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are embedding there returns an image data stream, the browser will create a rudimentary HTML document around that, and an `img` element. A plain image has no reason to "scale" to anything by its own volition - and since the iframe content is from a different origin, you can't easily inject your own styling either.

But you should be able to simply use an `img` instead of an `iframe` to begin with, to embed this into your page - and then you can format that image directly.